# How to generate a fixed byte array for a fixed IMEI in android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am new to android  development,I am working on a messaging app,now my task is to generate 20 or more byte array for a android device , this byte array should be same for a particular IMEI number, Please help me i am struck with this issue. I am able to generate a 14 byte array for a IMEI number , please check the code which i used to generate 14 byte array. Please help me

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String IMEI_Number = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

byte[] b=new byte[]{11,22,12,23,12,15,23,16,25,18,19,52,55,59,10,20,22,28,29,72} ;
new Random().nextBytes(b);
key=b.clone();
key=IMEI_Number.getBytes();
```

Comment: You want to turn a 14 byte IMEI number into a 20 or more byte array and the result must be deterministic (one IMEI will always produce the same result)? Sounds like a [Hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). Or you simply cycle through the bytes you have and append them until you have enough.

Comment: @zapl : thank you for the quick response, could you give me any reference material/link or any example for (Or you simply cycle through the bytes you have and append them until you have enough) to complete this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require that the output must be hard to turn back into the input you could for example just cycle through the input and append until you have enough bytes.

```
public static byte[] cyclicResize(byte[] input, int length) {
    byte[] result = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = input[i % input.length];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using that for example like

```
byte[] input = "Hello".getBytes();
byte[] output = cyclicResize(input, 13);
System.out.println(new String(output));
```

You would get the output

```
HelloHelloHel
```

That's very easy to turn back into the IMEI given that you know how long an IMEI is. It's a matter of security if there is such a requirement.

Comment: Thank you  very much  , i will try this method and update you if it works for me